# On estimating Covariance between a random variable and its non-linear transform

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable taking values on the real line.
Let $R(X) = max\{0, X\}$. Is it true that the covariance $Cov[X, R(X)] \ge 0$ irrespective of the distribution of $X$? Many experiments, as well as the intuition seem to suggest that their covariance must be non-negative. Is it true? If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: If $X$ is mean zero then I believe $\mathrm{Cov}(X,R(X)) = \int_\Omega X(\omega) R(X(\omega))d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{X>0} (X(\omega))^2 d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \geq 0$

Comment: No, it need not be zero mean. In fact, if the mean is negative, or zero, the non-negativeness emerges trivially from the definition : $ cov(X, R(X)) = E[X.R(X) ] - E[X]E[R(x)]$.  Because $E[R(x)]$ is always non-negative. But I can't figure out the case for  $E[X] > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${\rm Cov}\,(X,R(X))= \int_0^\infty x^2P(x)\,dx - \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty xP(x)\,dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^\infty xP(x)\,dx\right)$$
$$=\int_0^\infty x^2P(x)\,dx - \left(\int_{0}^\infty xP(x)\,dx\right)^2- \left(\int_{-\infty}^0 xP(x)\,dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^\infty xP(x)\,dx\right)$$
$$={\rm Var}\,R(X)- \left(\int_{-\infty}^0 xP(x)\,dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^\infty xP(x)\,dx\right)\geq 0.$$
The variance is positive by definition and the second term is minus the product of a negative and a positive integral.